# Why when calling the function in the numericUpDown changed event making everything slow after some times?

Tags: c#

This is the code in the `NumericUpDown` `ValueChanged` event:

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoThresholdCheck();
}
```

And this is the `DoThresholdCheck()` code:

```
private void DoThresholdCheck()
{

    List<int> f;
    List<string> fts;
    const string D6 = "000{0}.bmp";
    if (Directory.Exists(subDirectoryName))
    {



        if (!File.Exists(subDirectoryName + "\\" + averagesListTextFile + ".txt"))
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {




                f = new List<int>();
                fts = new List<string>();
                Bitmap myFiles;
                int counter = 0;
                double thershold = (double)numericUpDown1.Value;
                double max_min_threshold = (thershold / 100) * (max - min) + min;
                _fi = new DirectoryInfo(subDirectoryName).GetFiles("*.bmp");


                for (int i = 0; i < myNumbers.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (myNumbers[i] >= max_min_threshold)
                    {
                        string t = i.ToString("D6") + ".bmp";
                        if (File.Exists(subDirectoryName + "\\" + t))
                        {
                            button1.Enabled = false;
                            myTrackPanelss1.trackBar1.Enabled = true;



                        }
                        else
                        {
                            button1.Enabled = true;
                            myTrackPanelss1.trackBar1.Enabled = false;
                            pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.Weather_Michmoret;
                            label5.Visible = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (myTrackPanelss1.trackBar1.Maximum > 0)
                {
                    SetPicture(0);
                    myTrackPanelss1.trackBar1.Scroll += new EventHandler(trackBar1_Scroll);
                }
                if (_fi.Length >= 0)
                {
                    label15.Text = _fi.Length.ToString();
                    label15.Visible = true;
                }




        }
    }
    else
    {
        button1.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

What I want to do is; each time I change the `NumericUpDown` value in the program it will call the function in the event. In the event I create a new temp list each time and perform operations and make some checks on that list.

The problem is when I'm changing the `NumericUpDown` value a few times up and down in the program and then try to use the `trackBar1` to move between the images again, the `trackbar1` moves very slowly. When initially running the program, the slide bar in the `trackbar1` moves quickly and moves quickly between images, but when I change the `NumericUpDown` values the trackbar moves slowly for some reason.

I tried to add a `Timer2` and maybe use it in the `NumericUpDown` to make it call the function only after 500ms, for example, but it didn't solve it.

I can't figure out why its moving so slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'am not shore if it is the problem, but seems you adding event handler `myTrackPanelss1.trackBar1.Scroll += new EventHandler(trackBar1_Scroll);` but never removing it. So you always adding event handler and after a wile `trackBar1_Scroll` will be fired many times. Set breakpoint in `trackBar1_Scroll` and you will see how many times event handler is raised. Solution could be remove event handler or add it just one time.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you are performing quite a few IO operations. This can be a costly operation, particularly when you are running it frequently (i.e. on the `NumericUpDown`'s `ValueChanged` event). I would advise performing as much of this as possible in some initialization operation, not on each event firing.

Secondly, I'm not sure if it will actually affect the performance, but you keep attaching an event handler to the `trackBar1.Scroll` event. Since I don't see anywhere where you detach from this event, I would say that this is unnecessary. Either you need to better control the attachment and detachment, or simply attach once during control setup. It might also be worth creating a test program to see if attaching the same event handler multiple times does affect performance.

Finally, you could go about this operation by creating a background worker, on which you perform this operation each time it is signalled. If you make use of a wait handle, you can run the operation in a queue-like fashion. This would then not affect your UI operations, but you would have to be careful with what UI functions you call, as they can only be invoked on the UI thread. If you wish to know more about this, let me know and I will give you a brief example.

Comment: Slade what i did is in the numericupdown changed event before calling the function i just added myTrackPanelss1.trackBar1.Scroll -= new EventHandler(trackBar1_Scroll); unregister the event handler. im not sure if its a good solution but its working.

Comment: Do you need to be adding and removing that event handler? Can you not just add the event handler in the class constructor and then remove when destroying the class? That would be a better way to control the handling of the event. Unless there is a specific reason why you add and remove it in the current way.